# How can i make an input field not update all other instances of it?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

i am strting to play with Vue and i was wondering how i can update only the current edited text input value instead of updating all instances of it? I know it must be about the v-model , but i am a bit lost here.

Here is my code for the component :

```
Vue.component('app-list', {
    template: '<section id="app-item-field" class="columns is-multiline">' +
    '               <div class="column is-2" v-for="(list, index) in lists" >' +
    '                   <h2>{{list.title}}</h2>' +
    '                   <div class="field has-addons">' +
    '                       <input class="input is-small is-info" type="text" v-model="inputVal" placeholder="Nom de l\'item à ajouter">' +
    '                       <a class="button is-info is-small" :disabled="initValueIsSet === false" @click="addListItem(index)">Ajouter</a>' +
    '                   </div>' +
    '                   <app-list-items :items="list.items"></app-list-items>' +
    '               </div>' +
    '           </section>',
    props: ['lists'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            inputVal: null
        }
    },
    computed: {
        initValueIsSet: function () {
            if (this.inputVal === null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return this.inputVal.length > 0;
            }
        }
    },

    methods: {
        addListItem: function (index) {
            if (this.initValueIsSet) {
                this.$emit('new-list-item', index, this.inputVal, "http://www.google.ca");
                this.inputVal = "";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to turn `inputVal` into an array:

```js
data: function () {
    return {
        inputVal: []
    }
},
```

And use `index` from `v-for` to access it in the `v-model`. Template:

```html
<input class="input is-small is-info" type="text" v-model="inputVal[index]" placeholder="Nom de l\'item à ajouter">'
```

Also update the methods.

**Demo:**

```js
Vue.component('app-list-items', {
    template: '<span></span>'
});

Vue.component('app-list', {
    template: '<section id="app-item-field" class="columns is-multiline">' +
    '               <div class="column is-2" v-for="(list, index) in lists" >' +
    '                   <h2>{{list.title}}</h2>' +
    '                   <div class="field has-addons">' +
    '                       <input class="input is-small is-info" type="text" v-model="inputVal[index]" placeholder="Nom de l\'item à ajouter"> {{ inputVal[index] }}' +
    '                       <a class="button is-info is-small" :disabled="initValueIsSet(index) === false" @click="addListItem(index)">Ajouter</a>' +
    '                   </div>' +
    '                   <app-list-items :items="list.items"></app-list-items>' +
    '               </div>' +
    '           </section>',
    props: ['lists'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            inputVal: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        initValueIsSet: function (index) {
            if (this.inputVal[index] === null || this.inputVal[index] === undefined) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return this.inputVal[index].length > 0;
            }
        },
        addListItem: function (index) {
            if (this.initValueIsSet(index)) {
                this.$emit('new-list-item', index, this.inputVal[index], "http://www.google.ca");
                Vue.set(this.inputVal, index, ""); // https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats
            }
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lists: [{title: 'ana', items: []}, {title: 'bob', items: []}]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <app-list :lists="lists"></app-list>
</div>
```

Since `inputVal` is now an array, the computed `initValueIsSet` is now parameterized by the index. As computeds don't take arguments, we turned it into a method.

Comment: This is great, i was leaning in the right direction, but did not change computed value to method. This did the trick, thank